# Proof definite integral $\int_α^{π/2-α}f(\tan{x})dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-α $

Tags: definite-integrals

Given:

$$f(x) +f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) =1$$
I am trying to prove that
$$\int_α^{π/2-α}f(\tan{x})dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-α $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $$\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx,$$

$$I=\int_\alpha^{\frac\pi2-\alpha}f(\tan x)dx=\int_\alpha^{\frac\pi2-\alpha}f(\cot x)dx$$

$$I+I=\int_\alpha^{\frac\pi2-\alpha}[f(\tan x)+f(\cot x)]dx$$

Now set $x=\tan y$ in $f(x)+f\left(\dfrac1x\right)=1$

Comment: I used another theorem and went nowhere but did similar steps. How is the property/theorem that you used in first line called?

Comment: That is just a change of variables $t=a+b-x$.

Comment: @Parhs, Please let me know if you still have confusion?

Comment: I am trying to understand the first line

Comment: @Parhs, Try as mickep has suggested